# Best way to generate email reminders based on PowerBI reports?

Tags: email, powerbi

I am using powerBI to track different tasks over many projects - as a quality plan. Now I am looking for a way to send out email-reminders to project managers if their project needs attention.

In powerBI I get an overview and get my red lights in conditional formatting if a project needs attention - next step would be to automate reminders.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way for a data driven alert email currently available in Power BI, the closest would be to use [email subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-report-subscribe), that will send out emails at a defined scheduled.